# Why is Vue not reactive in this scenario?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have put together a bare-bones example that demonstrates a problem I'm having with Vue updating reactively.

Basically I have a table of buttons. When a user clicks on one of those buttons for the first time, that button will have backing data for it initialized and the button will be set to 'selected'.  When a user starts typing text in the input field, the selected button will show the input fields text in real-time.

However, even though the data has changed and the value has been updated for that button, it is not reflected in the UI.  In particular it seems that the getCell() method is not called again once the   data associated with the button changes.

```
<v-card v-if="getCell(curCol.id, curRow)">
```

Assuming I keep the data structure the same, am I missing something obvious in notifying Vue that the data has changed and to re-render?

https://codepen.io/uglyhobbitfeet/pen/GRgWXga

- I provided console statements in the example code to quickly help show what's happening

Comment: methods dont get invoked just because some data changed - use data or getters - those are reactive - alsothose methods didnt change just their return value

Comment: If I remove the methods and inline the data in the v-if I get the same issue

Comment: use Vue.set to set not initialized properties to be reactive, i suggest to read: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

Comment: I'm already doing that via $set calls

Comment: @ekjcfn3902039 the code `this.cells[col.id] = {};` is introducing a new key without `Vue.set`. Vue cannot detect key additions as described in [change detection caveats](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats)

Comment: Yep, that was it. Thanks Matt!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you have overcomplicated things a bit. The `computed` properties are meant for things like that.

So rather than having to add those cells dynamically using `Vue.set` every time, you could build up these "items" (or list of cells) while taking advantage of the `computed` reactivity.

Have a look the following example. The other "magic" is the [computed setter](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter) part, where it sets the currently active button text:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data: () => ({
    cols: [
      { id: 'a' },
      { id: 'b' },
      { id: 'c' }
    ],
    numRows: 2,
    selectedCell: {
      text: ''
    }
  }),

  computed: {
    inputText: {
      get() {
        return this.selectedCell.text;
      },
      set(value) {
        this.selectedCell.text = value;
      }
    },

    items() {
      return Array
        .apply(null, { length: this.numRows })
        .map(() => {
          return this.cols.map(col => ({
            cellId: col.id,
            text: 'default text'
          }))
        });
    }
  },

  methods: {
    setActive(col) {
      this.selectedCell = col;
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.input-container {
  text-align: center;
}

table {
  margin: 1rem auto;
}

button.active {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div class="input-container">
    <label>Click a Button, Then Type Some Text Here</label><br />
    <input v-model="inputText" ref="text" />
  </div>

  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="(cols, index) of items" :key="index">
        <td v-for="col of cols" :key="col.cellId">
          <button @click="setActive(col)" :class="{ active: selectedCell === col }">{{col.text}}</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, I explicitly do not want to pre-populate items due to the actual size of the data in my real-world situation. I want to generate it on the fly as needed. Thanks for the example though!

Comment: Well, this computed prop won't necessarily populate everything at once, it grows and/or shrinks as you add more (or remove) items. After all, it's a "computed" prop.

Comment: I have to agree - you can have a frozen list of 10k of items and use computed props to reflect slices based on data prop reactively